# Not able to load fusioncharts with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm trying to load fusion charts in my web page using AngularJS.

I have the following controller code in AngularJs.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCenter',myCenter);
myCenter.$inject = ['$scope','myCentre','$rootScope'];
function myCenter($scope, myCentre,$rootScope) {
    $scope.myData = [];
    $scope.myDataSource = {
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "Dummy Data",
                    "subCaption": "Dummy Data",
                    "xAxisName": "Dummy Data",
                    "yAxisName": "Dummy Data",
                    "numberSuffix": "K",
                    "theme": "fusion",
                },
                "data": [{
                    "label": "Venezuela",
                    "value": "290"
                }, {
                    "label": "Saudi",
                    "value": "260"
                }, {
                    "label": "Canada",
                    "value": "180"
                }, {
                    "label": "Iran",
                    "value": "140"
                }, {
                    "label": "Russia",
                    "value": "115"
                }, {
                    "label": "UAE",
                    "value": "100"
                }, {
                    "label": "US",
                    "value": "30"
                }, {
                    "label": "China",
                    "value": "30"
                }]
            };
}
```

I've got the following errors on the console.

[image: Error Image]

Following HTML is been added.

```
<div fusioncharts id="my-chart-id" width="700" height="400" type="column2d" dataSource="{{myDataSource}}">
</div>
```

I'm not able to recognize the error.

**EDIT 1:-**

I was able to remove that issue just by changing the **myDataSource** array in single line and then adding single quotes around it as below.

```
$scope.myDataSource = '{ "chart": { "caption": "Dummy Data", "subCaption": "Dummy Data", "xAxisName": "Dummy Data", "yAxisName": "Dummy Data", "numberSuffix": "K" }, "theme": "fusion", "data": [{ "label": "Venezuela", "value": "290" }, { "label": "Saudi", "value": "260" }, { "label": "Canada", "value": "180" }, { "label": "Iran", "value": "140" }, { "label": "Russia", "value": "115" }, { "label": "UAE", "value": "100" }, { "label": "US", "value": "30" }, { "label": "China", "value": "30" }]}';
```

And editing the HTML as following

```
<fusioncharts id="chartcontainer" chartid="chart1" width="100%" height="450" type="column2d" dataFormat= "json" dataSource="{{myDataSource}}"></fusioncharts>
```

After this edit Message appeared instead of chart *Loading Chart, Please Wait*.

What could be the problem in the data.

Comment: It's usually those `....`'s parts representing the missing parts inthe code  that are responsible for the actual error. Please create a **real** [mcve]

Comment: Error texts please also paste as text here, and format it.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that I can guess is that the ng-fusioncharts module is not loaded  at this state in the html:

What too you are using to build the scripts / html ? 
If it's gulp you can use this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort 
If you are doing it manually just change the order 
If you will use webpack i believe it will do it automatically fro you ..

The order in html shod be schematically:

```
AngularJS
fusioncharts
ng-fusioncharts
myApp
```

Comment: What should be the order then ?
I have added *angular* library first and then *fusion charts* library

Comment: Angular
ng-fusioncharts
myApp

Comment: I have added the libraries in the sequence you have mentioned. Version of AngularJS can cause issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample based on your above data

View

```
<html ng-app="HelloApp">

  <body ng-controller="MyController">

    <fusioncharts id="mychartcontainer" chartid="mychart" width="{{width}}" height="400" type="{{type}}" dataSource="{{dataSource}}"></fusioncharts>


  </body>

</html>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.type = "column2d";
  $scope.width = 600;
  $scope.dataSource = {
    "chart": {
      "caption": "Dummy Data",
      "subCaption": "Dummy Data",
      "xAxisName": "Dummy Data",
      "yAxisName": "Dummy Data",
      "numberSuffix": "K",
      "theme": "fusion",
    },
    "data": [{
      "label": "Venezuela",
      "value": "290"
    }, {
      "label": "Saudi",
      "value": "260"
    }, {
      "label": "Canada",
      "value": "180"
    }, {
      "label": "Iran",
      "value": "140"
    }, {
      "label": "Russia",
      "value": "115"
    }, {
      "label": "UAE",
      "value": "100"
    }, {
      "label": "US",
      "value": "30"
    }, {
      "label": "China",
      "value": "30"
    }]
  };


});
```

Here is a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/1k07wvop/

Comment: I tried your snippet, but results in the same error as mentioned in the image.

Comment: please check the above demo it is working fine at my end. also check with the latest angular-fusioncharts plugin and fusioncharts version

Comment: I have used the latest angular-fusioncharts plugin and fusioncharts version

Answer (score 0):

In the app, include the ng-fusioncharts directive as a dependency. If you are looking for where to add the dependency, look for the call to angular.module in your code

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ng-fusioncharts"])
```

Add the fusioncharts directive
In your HTML, define a   element with fusioncharts  directive where you want to add the chart.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
 <div fusioncharts
      width="600"
      height="400"
      type="column2d"
      dataSource="{{myDataSource}}" >
 </div>
</div>

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    //Define the `myDataSource` scope variable.  
    $scope.myDataSource = {
       chart: {
           caption: "Harry's SuperMart",
           subCaption: "Top 5 stores in last month by revenue",
           numberPrefix: "$",
           theme: "fint"
       },
       data:[{
           label: "Bakersfield Central",
           value: "880000"
       },
       {
           label: "Garden Groove harbour",
           value: "730000"
       },
       {
           label: "Los Angeles Topanga",
           value: "590000"
       },
       {
           label: "Compton-Rancho Dom",
           value: "520000"
       },
       {
           label: "Daly City Serramonte",
           value: "330000"
       }]
    };
    });
```

To know more about it please check - https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/angular-fusioncharts/

Here is the integration docs - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angularjs/your-first-chart-using-angularjs